# Use FOR variable as column value

Tags: r, loops

I'd like to use the FOR variable as column reference.

I have 2 dataframes (df1,df2) where df1 has all my data and and df2 only has the first column with the key.

I'd like to be able to populate df2 with the sum of rows if those conditions are true.

Here's the script:

```
for (actRow in nrow(df2)) {
  for (j in 1:6) {
    df2[actRow, (j+1)] = sum(df1[2]==df2[actRow, 1] & df1[3]==j)
  }
}
```

Ex:

- At the first row of df2 the key is "A" and the next row the key is
  "B"
- In df1, there's a lot of "A" and "B" in column 2 and a value between 1 and 6 in the column 3.

I'd like to count the amount of A in `df1[2]` that has the value "1" in the third column and put that sum in df2 at the row1, column2. Then loop again to write the sum of A with the value "2" in the third column of df2 and so on until the value is "6". When it's done we do the same thing but with "B"

**problem**
For now I only get 0 in my df2 but when I change

```
df2[actRow, (j+1)] = sum(df1[2]==df2[actRow, 1] & df1[3]==j)
```

by this

```
df2[1, 2] = sum(df1[2]==df2[1, 1] & df1[3]==1)
```

it turns out that I have 25 "A" where the third column = 1

Comment: please provide the actual data with dput()

Comment: You should include at least the minimal reproducible example witha subset of your actual data in the body of the question, not in links to the data

Comment: I'm sorry everithing is for a french guy so it's possible that you don't understand what it is...

Comment: use paste the output pf `dput(your_dataframe)` so we can cave the data

Comment: Here's the dput of df1 : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1E9wfEHTUIlAtBO3MdN8G9VevBavwuwfkviVJ9aPgAa4/edit?usp=sharing

its too long for a comment

Comment: This is both too long and not provided in the body of the answer. Try sharing just a small subset of that data, the necessary minumum that would help us reproduce and understand your questions

Comment: Hi Vincent, 1) Don't share any external links here. Your question needs to be self-sufficient which should make sense for future visitors even when those links expire and/or are deleted. Data should be included in the question itself. 2) We don't need all of your data to help you. Please include small sample of your dataset using which you can explain your question and show your expected output for it so that we can verify our answers using it. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: I tried the best i can:

> dput(df1[2:3])
structure(list(Key= c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A"), Recouv_chp = c(1L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -54L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(df2)
structure(list(Key = c("A", "B")), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `Recouv_chp` column as factor and use `table` to count their occurrences.

```
df1$Recouv_chp <- factor(df1$Recouv_chp, min(df1$Recouv_chp):max(df1$Recouv_chp))
table(df1)
#If you have more than two columns in df1, use
#table(df1$Key, df1$Recouv_chp)

# Recouv_chp
#Key 1 2 3 4 5 6
#  A 2 0 1 0 0 1
#  B 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- tibble::tribble(    ~Key, ~Recouv_chp,
                      "A",          1,
                      "A",          6,
                      "B",          3,
                      "A",          3,
                      "B",          2,
                      "B",          1,
                      "A",          1)

df1 |> 
  count(Key, Recouv_chp) |> 
  complete(Key, Recouv_chp = full_seq(Recouv_chp, 1), fill = list(n = 0)) |> # EDIT: Added to complete the sequence of values
  arrange(Recouv_chp) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Recouv_chp, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))

# A tibble: 2 x 7
  Key     `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         2     0     1     0     0     1
2 B         1     1     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: Yes it seems to work! but how could i get column '4' and '5' with 0?